# Samsung Star 2G GT-S5233S Contact Sync error

Tags: contacts

I recently got my Samsung star system software upgraded by the authorized Samsung service center. Since then, whenever I try to sync my contacts via Outlook onto my phone, I get a timeout period expired error. It happens after a certain number of contacts have been synced to the phone.

I've tried to removed/edit some records, but that didn't help. Does anyone have any ideas? Typing back each contact will be too bad.

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the phone tool didnt work out. i had to send my contacts via outlook express using bluetooth.